# Ubuntu 16.04 and Win 7 fails to boot after GRUB

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

There is a dual boot of a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 and a Windows 7 on my machine, and after I choose Ubuntu in the GRUB menu it falis to boot, the screen stays black. When I choose Win 7, it starts to boot, then after a blue death the computer restarts. After the restart both systems boot perfectly fine. What causes this problem,and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What brand/model system? It is an UEFI system with Windows & Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode?

Comment: Intel core 2 duo E4600, 2Gb RAM, Nvidia 8600GT, on a Gigabyte motherboard. This problem never happened before, I had a dual boot with these to OSes on this machine. It appeared after the fresh 16.04 install.

Comment: That is old enough to be before UEFI, so just BIOS. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26291670/

Comment: This is after the boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26291694

Comment: If you have two drives and operating systems on each drive, better to use Boot-Repair's advanced mode. Install Windows boot loader on Windows drive and grub on Ubuntu drive. Set BIOS to boot Ubuntu drive. But since grub only boots working Windows you may then be able to directly boot Windows when needed.  Also avoids the Flexnet issue. What video driver do you have. Older card like yours should work with nouveau, but if you install the incorrect nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository you will have video issues, and must purge the incorrect one.

Comment: I've done what you've suggested, but absolutely nothing changed. It doesn't matter which nvidia driver I use, it fails to boot anyway, same with Win 7. Would a complete Ubuntu reinstall have any effect on this matter?

Comment: Only one nVidia driver is correct, and if you have wrong one, you must totally purge the incorrect one, or you have conflicts. New driver, does not totally overwrite old driver. Updated driver search by nVidia model, do not download, just check correct driver version
http://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: I always install with Additional Drivers the recommended, closed and tested driver.

Comment: Looks like the problem solved itself. I removed the video card, put it back in, and the problem is gone. I still have no idea what caused the problem though.